# set Slider bootstrap value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem in my bootstrap slider, I want to change its value from javascript, but my code doesn't work for me.

JS:

```
var val=1;
$("#gravite").slider('setValue',val);
$($(this).attr('data-slider-value')).modal('show');
```

HTML:

```
<input id="gravite" name="gravite" type="text"
              data-provide="slider"
              data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3]"
              data-slider-ticks-labels='["Faible", "Moyenne", "Urgent"]'
              data-slider-min="1"
              data-slider-max="3"
              data-slider-step="1"
              data-slider-value=""
              data-slider-tooltip="hide" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
$('#gravite').slider({
    value : 0,
});
```